# Hibernate session.flush() causes ORA-00001: unique constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method that inserts thousands of records to the database using hibernate.

According to this [article](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html), flushing and clearing helps to release some precious memory, and the code below does this every 100 records. But the problem:

ORA-00001: unique constraint (OWNER.FOO_TABLE_PK) violated

always occurs when the code session.flush() is invoked, which is after the 100th save (the PK of FOO_TABLE is a simple long id). I have tried removing the session.flush() and session.clear() entirely and added session.evict(obj) after the session.save() and that fixed the problem. I am not sure if it is a good practice though.

Would you guys have any idea why session.flush() causes a unique constraint error? Flushing and clearing at regular intervals are heavily suggested, but I am not sure if I am using them properly. Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void bulkSave(List<Foo> objList) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        if (objList != null) {
            if (!objList.isEmpty()) {
                int counter = 0;

                for (Foo obj : objList) {
                    session.save(objList);
                    counter++;


                    if ((counter % 100) == 0) {
                        session.flush();
                        session.clear();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are your `Foo` objects created?

Comment: @SubOptimal The Foo objects were created after a process of parsing excel files. They all have 0 ids which are the primary keys in the DB..

Comment: If they have all `0` as primary key, then it's normal that you get `unique constraint` exception. How this primary key id is annotated in the Foo class?

Comment: It is annotated like this:
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idGenerator", sequenceName = "TABLE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
 @Column(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false)

I believe that session.save() will provide a new ID for the object using the generated ID from the TABLE_ID_SEQ, so the 0 ids is for new objects is normal.

Comment: @SubOptimal, I would like to apologize as I have found the cause of the unique constraint. This is not the fault of hibernate because it only uses the ID provided by the assigned sequence generator. Someone manually uploaded data to the database using a custom ID which bypassed the generator. When hibernate caught up with this number, the ID provided by the sequence generator is already used in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well flushing causes the state to be flushed through to the database. If there's a primary key violation, there's something wrong with how you're assigning the primary key for your object.

Comment: Yes you are right, I figured out the issue after a while. This is not Hibernate's fault.

Answer (score 1):

After a more in-depth investigation, I have determined that this is not the fault of Hibernate. Hibernate uses the number provided by the ID Sequence Generator as primary keys. Someone manually uploaded a test data which used IDs not accounted for by the Sequence Generator. Eventually when hibernate caught-up, it cannot use the ID provided by the generator because the ID already exists in the Database, hence the Unique Constraint violation after the session.flush().